# Group by day queried data and lay out to a grid

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grid

I have a somewhat-social-network logging project which let users input any activity they have done the whole day.

On my db I have a 'logs' table which have the following fields:

```
| log_id | log_content | log_date | log_author |
```

My problem is, how can I do a query which would fetch the first n days then display its result in a grid view like this:

```
| Monday, December 7, 2013
| log_content, log_author, 6 AM | log_content, log_author, 8:30 AM | ...|

| Tuesday, December 8, 2013
| log_content, log_author, 7:10 AM | log_content, log_author, 12:00 NN | log...|

| Wednesday, December 9, 2013
| log_content, log_author, 6:30 PM |

| Thursday, December 10, 2013
| log_content, log_author, 9:53 AM | log_content, log_author, 4:02 PM | ...|

| Friday, December 11, 2013
| log_content, log_author, 1:34 PM |
```

I know I can't do a query for the whole 'logs' table since it will lead to bottleneck when the logs grow. I was thinking of doing a query in bits, and when the user scrolls down, another background query would run for the next set of data to display(*using limits and offsets*).

My query as of the moment looks like this:

```
function fetch_logs($group_id, $limit, $offset){
        $this->db->select('l.log_id, l.log_date, l.log_content, u.username');
        $this->db->from('logs AS l');
        $this->db->join('log_group_ref AS r', 'l.log_id = r.log_id');
        $this->db->join('users AS u', 'l.log_author = u.user_id');
        $this->db->where('r.group_id', $group_id);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

But I have no idea how to group the queried data by days and lay them into grid.

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap with grid so I can lay down each log into a grid nicely then just add scroll bars if there are more logs.

Update:

So I updated my code based on raheel shan's second method but I can't seem to get the data that I wanted until I added:

```
$this->db->group_by(l.log_date);
```

basing on Exander's code which fetch the correct set of data although not formatted same as raheel shan's.

So out of those two, here's my updated query:

```
$select =   array(
                            "DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%a , %b %d , %Y') AS LogDate",
                            "GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_id) AS LogIDs",
                            "GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_content) AS LogContents",
                            "GROUP_CONCAT(u.username) AS LogAuthors",
                            "GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%h:%i %p')) AS LogTimes"
                        );
            $this->db->select($select);
            $this->db->from('logs AS l');
            $this->db->join('log_group_ref AS r', 'l.log_id = r.log_id');
            $this->db->join('users AS u', 'l.log_author = u.user_id');
            $this->db->where('r.group_id', $group_id);
            $this->db->group_by('l.log_date');
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now, I'll have to deal with exploding each LogContents, LogAuthors, LogTimes and group them back in array. I need to study raheel shan's code again.

Update:
I finally got all the things I need to achieve this. I'll mark raheel shan's as accepted since I can only accept one. Though Exander's is also correct plus lesser code which make it great.

Comment: please explain your output what you really want.

Comment: @raheelshan, the final output should look like what I have describe above. A day could contain any number of logs, which is displayed in a row. Another day would be another row. Each log on a certain day is arranged in a grid so that I can choose to display 5 grids of log for all days and hide the rest and just use scrollbars to show the hidden logs so everything will be neat. Something like this: [layout](http://i.imgur.com/Bu33q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.
View Demo 

#### Here

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%a , %b %d , %Y') as LogDate,
    DATE(l.log_date) as LDate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(r.data) as LogData
FROM logs as l
INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT 
                    logs.log_date,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(other) as data     
            FROM logs
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT 
                            log_date,
                            CONCAT(log_content, ' | ', log_author , ' | ' , DATE_FORMAT(log_date,'%h:%i %p')) as other 
                        FROM logs
                        GROUP BY log_date
            ) as t ON t.log_date = logs.log_date
            GROUP BY log_date
) as r ON r.log_date = l.log_date
GROUP BY LDate
```

And in Codeigniter

```
$query  ="  SELECT
                DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%a , %b %d , %Y') as LogDate,
                DATE(l.log_date) as LDate,
                GROUP_CONCAT(r.data) as LogData
            FROM logs as l
            INNER JOIN  (
                        SELECT 
                                logs.log_date,
                                GROUP_CONCAT(other) as data     
                        FROM logs
                        LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT 
                                        log_date,
                                        CONCAT(log_content, ' | ', log_author , ' | ' , DATE_FORMAT(log_date,'%h:%i %p')) as other 
                                    FROM logs
                                    GROUP BY log_date
                        ) as t ON t.log_date = logs.log_date
                        GROUP BY log_date
            ) as r ON r.log_date = l.log_date
            GROUP BY LDate";

$result =   $this->db->query($query);
return $result->result();
```

Learning Points

Left Joins
Group_Concat
Concat
DATE_FORMAT

EDITS :
2nd Method

if you want to do it with php it is easy. Here is how you can do it. First Model function

```
function fetch_logs($group_id, $limit, $offset)
{
        $select =   array(
                        "DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%a , %b %d , %Y') as LogDate",
                        "GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_id) as LogIDs",
                        "GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_content) as LogContents",
                        "GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_author) as LogAuthors",
                        "GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%h:%i %p')) LogTimes"
                    );
        $this->db->select($select);
        $this->db->from('logs AS l');
        $this->db->join('log_group_ref AS r', 'l.log_id = r.log_id');
        $this->db->join('users AS u', 'l.log_author = u.user_id');
        $this->db->where('r.group_id', $group_id);
        $this->db->group_by(l.log_date);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

And Now in Controller function

```
function getLogs()
{
    $result =   $this->yourmodel->fetch_logs();
    $data   =   array();
    $i  =   0;

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $logids     =   explode(',',$row['LogIDs']);
        $logcontents    =   explode(',',$row['LogContents']);
        $logauthors =   explode(',',$row['LogAuthors']);
        $logtimes       =   explode(',',$row['LogTimes']);

        $counter    =   count($logids);
        $test   =   array();

            for($j=0;$j<$counter;$j++)
            {
                $test[] =   $logcontents[$j] .','. $logauthors[$j] .','.$logtimes[$j];
            }
        $data[$i]['logdata']    =   implode('|',$test);
        $data[$i]['logdate']    =   $row['LogDate'];
        unset($test);
        $i++;
    }

    $viewdata['data']   =   $data;
    $this->load->view('my_view',$viewdata);
}
```

Comment: Based on the demo, I think you have achieved what I wanted. I was thinking that the laying of the data will be done by PHP, I never thought it could all be done in SQL. Now I will have to understand this(hope I can) and test if can create the final output. Are there any other way to do this? The query seems really complex. But really, thanks!

Comment: the best practice is that get everything from query so that you dont have to do a lot of conditions and looping on php end. This query is not complex. If you learn to use derieved queries you can do anything. And this gives you write less code on php and. Otherwise you may have to use multiple loops with php.

Comment: @Zaski See the Edited part of my answer

Comment: Okay, I have tried the 1st one and got it working, but I can't manipulate the concatenated output (LogData) so that I can lay each of the logs in a grid. Only way I can think of doing it is splitting each returned LogData to get individual logs. Is there any way that the output of LogData isn't a concat but instead an array? I will also try your second method, that one seemed to address my second question.. but not totally sure. Thanks again!

Comment: if you use php explode you will get all the things as an array

Comment: I get an error 'Column 'log_id' in field list is ambiguous' using the second method. Could be an alias prefix lacking...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure, but this query seems to be able to get the result that you need without any subqueries:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date,'%W , %M %d , %Y') AS day,
    GROUP_CONCAT(l.log_content, ', ', u.username, ', ', DATE_FORMAT(l.log_date, '%l:%i %p') ORDER BY l.log_date SEPARATOR ' | ') AS activity
FROM logs as l
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = l.log_author
INNER JOIN log_group_ref r ON r.log_id = l.log_id
WHERE r.group_id = **<YOUR_GROUP_ID>**
GROUP BY DATE(l.log_date) ASC;
```

You may see the example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea57e/1) (partially copied and pasted from raheel shan's example).

Comment: @Extander ! your technique really minimized the query. I never knew that we can use concat like this using GROUP_CONCAT. So you deserve +1.

Comment: @Extander, this is indeed better! Another +1 for you. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this--

```
$this->db->select("l.log_id, date_format(l.log_date,'%W %M, %d %Y') D, l.log_content, u.username");
        $this->db->from('logs AS l');
        $this->db->join('log_group_ref AS r', 'l.log_id = r.log_id');
        $this->db->join('users AS u', 'l.log_author = u.user_id');
        $this->db->where('r.group_id', $group_id);
        $this->db->order_by('l.log_date','desc');
        $this->db->limit($limit);

        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I just formated the date (l.log_date) and added order_by clause so that it fetch first N days activities.

Comment: I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in C:\xampp...(maybe just a quote problem). But anyways, as what I have understood, it should return an array of data from the first 5 days in a descending date order. However, how will I process it on the php side so I can identify that this log belongs to this day and should be in this row... this one is on that day and should be on that row? I'm really confused. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I found out you need to add false as second parameter on the select portion to avoid error. Also I wonder what's with the D after the date_format?